# How to dismiss the UIActivityViewController during a UI test with Xcode 11 & iOS 13

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller, xcode-ui-testing

Apple has re-designed the share sheet that appears, which has now broken my UI tests.

I have attempted to record a new UI test through Xcode, but as soon as I tap on the dismiss button, the test terminates so I have not been able to capture the event.

Ultimately, I just want to know how I can access the gray 'X' shown with the arrow below:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have just tested this with Xcode 13 and have found that the original answer no longer works. However, I am keeping it for posterity, or those using previous versions of Xcode.

## Xcode 13

I have  tested this with Xcode 13.0 and verified it works for iPhone and iPad:

```swift
let activityListView = app.otherElements.element(matching: .other,
                                                 identifier: "ActivityListView")
XCTAssertTrue(activityListView.waitForExistence(timeout: 2.0))
activityListView.buttons["Close"].tap()
```

## Previous versions

After some trial and error, I was able to locate where my specific elements were with the following:

`app.otherElements.element(boundBy: 1).buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()`

Using `app.otherElements.element(boundBy: 1)` would identify the share sheet for me. I had attempted to locate it through accessibility identifiers, but I could not find one that worked, including previously valid ones used in iOS 12 and below.

> Please note that based on the layout of your screen, the index value
> may differ from what I am seeing.

Next, `.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()` was used to locate the **Close** button. I again attempted to use identifiers, but could not find anything that represented the button.

When I attempted to discern additional information through the console while testing, I would always wind up crashing the test. This result was surprising, as I was able to query these elements with Xcode 10.

Ultimately, I would like to find working identifier values so that I can have something that works reliably across products, without the trial and error to find the share sheet's index value.

## For iPad

The following will dismiss the popover for an iPad:

```
app.otherElements["PopoverDismissRegion"].tap()
```

Comment: Is there an update? I get `Failed to synthesize event: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 3118, elementOrHash.elementID: 4354340448.106. (Underlying Error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 3118, elementOrHash.elementID: 4354340448.106)`

Comment: @JCutting8 I have updated the answer, perhaps this addresses your issue?